# Sections of Normal Scheme is also Normal

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

A scheme $X$ is normal, if stalks $\mathcal{O}_{\mathfrak{p}}$ are integral closed for all $\mathfrak{p}\in X$.

A ring $A$ is normal, if it's integrally closed.

I want to show if $X$ is a normal, integral scheme, then for all open subset $U\subseteq X$, the section $\Gamma(U,\mathcal{O}_X)$ is also normal. In particular, the global section $\Gamma(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$ is normal, I really need this conclusion.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: This is true. See Liu's Proposition 4.1.5(b) on page 116 of 'Algebraic Geometry and Arithmetic Curves'.

Comment: @Daniel verythanks